# The table striping in the 'Developer Profiles\Key Territories' section of the 2022 Developer Survey results make it extremely difficult to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey-2022

Link: https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2022/#developer-profile-key-territories

This is the case regardless of the light mode/dark mode selection.

---

Light mode:

> [image]

Dark mode:

> [image]

Can this be fixed so that, e.g. black (rather than white) text appears on the light grey background?

Comment: Bonus bug: "Vietnam" is [Vietnam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vietnam), not [Viet Nam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjX7w.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed by changing the background stripes, which now provide a higher contrast, and thus a higher readability.

Light mode:

[image]

Dark mode:
[image]